Node Crypto Decipher Working Even With Altered AuthTag aes-256-gcm
I have some code that does encrypts and decrypts a string using node crypto; however, when I pass in a different authTag into the decipher.setAuthTag, it still decrypts succesfully. I was wondering if this is the expected behavior. If not, what would be the proper way to authenticate the text has not been tampered with?
Standard Encryption:
const { createCipheriv, randomBytes, createDecipheriv } = require("crypto");
const text = "hello world";

const iv = randomBytes(16); // Initialization vector
const secret_key = Buffer.from(
  "2ef08b673cff8759d7df0546e8ff273415e072237c81c192ebe52ac1b10eb684",
  "hex"
);
const cipher = createCipheriv("aes-256-gcm", secret_key, iv);

let encrypted = cipher.update(text, "utf8", "hex");

encrypted += cipher.final("hex");
const authTag = cipher.getAuthTag().toString("hex");

const encryptedString = `${iv.toString("hex")}:${encrypted}:${authTag}`;


Standard Decryption:
const [iv_dcrypt, encrypted_dcrypt, authTag_dcrypt] =
  encryptedString.split(":");

const decipher = createDecipheriv(
  "aes-256-gcm",
  secret_key,
  Buffer.from(iv_dcrypt, "hex")
);

// Using a different auth tag
decipher.setAuthTag(Buffer.from(`${authTag_dcrypt}7`, "hex"));

let decrypted = decipher.update(encrypted_dcrypt, "hex", "utf8");
try {
  decrypted += decipher.final("utf8");
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log("Authentication failed");
}

console.log(decrypted); // No error is thrown and original message is shown


You didn't actually change anything. You appended a single hex digit, but Buffer.from() ignores it because the hex string now contains an odd number of characters, and in that case, the last one is ignored. Try changing the last two hex digits, appending stuff just makes the tag have an invalid length.
